# how to store and retrieve multidimensional array in local-storage JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

store data and retrieve multidimensional array in local storage java-script

Here I need to store array in local storage. and How do I retrieve?

Comment: Please try to at least search for answers before asking a question: https://www.google.com/search?q=store+array+in+localstorage&oq=sotre+array+in+loca&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3632j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 4):

As only strings can be assigned to localStorage, you have to convert the array to a string before assigning.
Convert the array into a JSON string using `JSON.stringify()` and using `localStorage.setItem()` store it in localStorage.

```js
var num = [
    ['inp1','inp2'],
    ['inp3','inp4']
];
localStorage.setItem('arr',JSON.stringify(num));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) combined  with [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) methods `setItem()` and `getItem()`:

To store:

```
localStorage.setItem('myItem', JSON.stringify(myMultidimensionalArray))
```

And to get the stored data with key `myItem`:

```
const array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myItem'))
```

Answer (score 1):

With [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) we are limited to store data as strings, therefore:

- Use `JSON.stringify` to serialize the data to a string, before storing it in the local storage

  ```
  const input = [[1], [2], [3]];
  localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(input));
  ```
- Use `JSON.parse` to deserialize the data back to array when reading it form the local storage

  ```
  const arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```js
var multidimensionarray = [
   ['1','2'],
   ['3','4']
];
localStorage.setItem('__array', JSON.stringify(multidimensionarray));

console.log(localStorage.getItem('__array'));
```

Comment: Notice that JQuery is no needed in your code

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is very simple data storage. It stores key (string) of which value is also (string and only string!). You need to use `JSON.stringify(...)` to store data and then parse it back `JSON.parse(...)`